# How to run 1 complete loop-circle than refresh page than check with if(), if the condition are met, run 1 loop circle again

Tags: javascript, php, for-loop

What i want is after user click specific button on my webpage, I will check with if(isset()) than run the follow commend for loop.

This is what i have done so far. If $balance is 10 than for loop should run 10 times. For loop run instantly 10 times without refreshing the page but sleep() function help delay it. I need to refresh the page every 1 loop complete than continue the rest 9 loops. Every loop need to refresh page every time its run.

```
$balance = '10';
$wallet = $_SESSION['wallet'];

if(isset($_POST['click'])){
    if($balance != 0){
        for($x = 0; $x < $balance; $x++){
            $sql = $conn->query("UPDATE wallets SET balance = balance - 1 WHERE wallet = '$wallet' " );
            //some code to complete this 
            ....
            //this is where the page to refresh
            header("location: click.php?e=2");
        }
        sleep(5);
    }
    else{
        header("location: click.php?e=1");
    }
}
```

What i expected is ....
1 loop complete refresh page 1 time than continue another 1 loop than refresh page 1 more time than continue....

Comment: `session_start()` at the beginning of your code

Comment: @quickSwap thanks for the advice but it just part of the code, it is not all the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any loop its just decrement values will work.

```
$balance = ($_SESSION['balance'] ?? 0);
$wallet  = $_SESSION['wallet'];
if (isset($_POST['click'])) {
    if ($balance > 0) {
        // for ($x = 0; $x < $balance; $x++) {
        $sql                = $conn->query("UPDATE wallets SET balance = balance - 1 WHERE wallet = '$wallet' ");
        $_SESSION['wallet'] = intval($_SESSION['wallet']) - 1;
        $_SESSION['balance'] = $_SESSION['balance']-1;
        //some code to complete this
        //....
        //this is where the page to refresh
        header("location: click.php?e=2");
        // }
        sleep(5);
    } else {
        header("location: click.php?e=1");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the part `$_SESSION['wallet'] = $_SESSION['wallet'] - 1;` wallet is varchar not interger.

Comment: Check now, but I think still wouldn't affect that much. Once check and let me know if its working

Comment: It work for the process but after refresh, it didn't check if() condition again. User need to click that button again to work. What i need to the code need to run after one click made by user.

Comment: $balance is from database actually, i wrote it as fix variable to be easier to understand, $wallet can't be subtract 1 as the type is not integer, it is string. After the update we are getting no where.